# Apns feedback return incorrect device token

Tags: apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

I bulid up a notification service with PushSharp. Recently, I got some feedback told that some device token were expired(from Device Subscription Event of PushSharp). But the app on those devices are not removed.

Does anyone experience same situation?

Comment: What happens when you try to send a push notification to that device token? Is it delivered?

Comment: Yes, the notification delivered(APNS give a response, ie. I got a sent event in PushSharp). But the device didn't receive the notification.

Comment: Perhaps the device disabled push notifications. Check if push notifications are enabled for that device.

Comment: OK, I will check it when it happens again. Thanks for advice, @Eran